# Amend BigQuery Data Using Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-bigquery

I wonder whether someone may be able to help me please?

I've put together the script below which amends data in my bigQuery table:

```
function runQuery() {
   var projectId = 'bigquery';
   var datasetId = 'Test';  
   var date = '20181206';
   var tableId = 'ga_sessions_'+date;
// Configuration
   var configuration = {
    "query": {
    "useQueryCache": false,
    "writeDisposition": "WRITE_TRUNCATE",
    "createDisposition": "CREATE_IF_NEEDED",
    "allowLargeResults": true,
    "useLegacySql": false,
    query: "SELECT * EXCEPT (hits),ARRAY( SELECT AS STRUCT * EXCEPT (page, appInfo, eventInfo ),(SELECT "+
"AS STRUCT page.* EXCEPT (pagePath, pagePathLevel1, pagePathLevel2, pagePathLevel3, pagePathLevel4), "+
"REGEXP_REPLACE(page.pagePath, r'([^\\?]+?)(\\?.+)','\\\\1') AS pagePath,"+
"REGEXP_REPLACE(page.pagePath, r'([^\\?]+?)(\\?.+)','\\\\1') AS pagePathLevel1, "+
"REGEXP_REPLACE(page.pagePath, r'([^\\?]+?)(\\?.+)','\\\\1') AS pagePathLevel2,"+
"REGEXP_REPLACE(page.pagePath, r'([^\\?]+?)(\\?.+)','\\\\1') AS pagePathLevel3, "+
"REGEXP_REPLACE(page.pagePath, r'([^\\?]+?)(\\?.+)','\\\\1') AS pagePathLevel4, "+
"`bigquery.Test.ga_sessions_20181206`",
  destinationTable: { projectId: projectId, datasetId: datasetId, tableId: tableId } 
   }
 };

  var job = {
    "configuration": configuration
  };

  var jobResult = BigQuery.Jobs.insert(job, "bigquery");
  Logger.log(jobResult);
}
```

The code works, but I'd now like to change this line:

```
"`bigquery.Test.ga_sessions_20181206`"
```

So that rather than the end user having to type in the date, it's picked up from the 'var date'.

I've amended the code to:

```
function runQuery() {
   var projectId = 'bigquery';
   var datasetId = 'Test';  
   var date = '20181206';
   var tableId = 'ga_sessions_'+date;
// Configuration
   var configuration = {
    "query": {
    "useQueryCache": false,
    "writeDisposition": "WRITE_TRUNCATE",
    "createDisposition": "CREATE_IF_NEEDED",
    "allowLargeResults": true,
    "useLegacySql": false,
    query: "SELECT * EXCEPT (hits),ARRAY( SELECT AS STRUCT * EXCEPT (page, appInfo, eventInfo ),(SELECT "+
"AS STRUCT page.* EXCEPT (pagePath, pagePathLevel1, pagePathLevel2, pagePathLevel3, pagePathLevel4), "+
"REGEXP_REPLACE(page.pagePath, r'([^\\?]+?)(\\?.+)','\\\\1') AS pagePath,"+
"REGEXP_REPLACE(page.pagePath, r'([^\\?]+?)(\\?.+)','\\\\1') AS pagePathLevel1, "+
"REGEXP_REPLACE(page.pagePath, r'([^\\?]+?)(\\?.+)','\\\\1') AS pagePathLevel2,"+
"REGEXP_REPLACE(page.pagePath, r'([^\\?]+?)(\\?.+)','\\\\1') AS pagePathLevel3, "+
"REGEXP_REPLACE(page.pagePath, r'([^\\?]+?)(\\?.+)','\\\\1') AS pagePathLevel4, "+
"`bigquery.Test.ga_sessions_*` "+
"WHERE "+
      "  _TABLE_SUFFIX = 'date' " ,      

  destinationTable: { projectId: projectId, datasetId: datasetId, tableId: tableId } 
   }
 };

  var job = {
    "configuration": configuration
  };

  var jobResult = BigQuery.Jobs.insert(job, "bigquery");
  Logger.log(jobResult);
}
```

The problem I now have is that rather than amending the data, it completely deletes it.

Could someone have a look at this please and let me know where I've gone wrong.

Many thanks and kind regards

Chris

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here:

```
"  _TABLE_SUFFIX = 'date' "
```

The query is literally looking for a suffix named `'date'`, rather than whatever the user specified. Someone else who has an Apps Script environment may be able to give a more specific answer, but the basic idea is that you should use a [query parameter](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/parameterized-queries) instead, so you would use `@date` (no quotes) instead of `'date'`, and you would pass the user-specified date as a STRING type query parameter with the request.

Comment: Hi @elliott Brossard, thank you for this. Unfortunately, although it no longer deletes the data, it doesn't amend the data either.

Many thanks and kind regards

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean that it doesn't amend the data. The code that you provided isn't waiting for the query to complete or checking its status, so maybe that's the problem.

Comment: Hi. Yeah maybe that is the issue. I'll continue to work on it because it's clearly containing some issues. Many thanks for your help. Regards. Chris